# Android / Java - How can I find the row in which a spinner is contained in a listView

Tags: android, listview, tags, spinner, adapter

I have a listView where each row contains a textView and a Spinner. I can populate both and I can select from the Spinner with no problem. When the user selects from the spinner I can read the selection using onItemSelected().

My problem is that I can't figure out how to identify which row within the listView was selected.

I've tried using a setTag() and setId(), but can't get either of them to give me what I need.

I also tried placing a transparent button over the row and used an onClickListener, but the button obscures the spinner so you don't actually activate the spinner.

Below is my code. I'd be grateful for any help or pointers in the right direction.

I've viewed dozens of related posts on SO, but can't find one which actually answers this problem. Apologies if I've missed it.

Thanks

Code for getView() in adapter.

```
public class AdapterSelectEventPayment extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<String> mSpinnerItems;
    private ArrayList<String> mDataSource;

    private Context mContext;
    private AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener mSpinnerItemSelectedListener;

    public AdapterSelectEventPayment(ArrayList<String> data, ArrayList<String> spinnerItems, Context context) {
        mDataSource = data;
        mContext = context;
        mSpinnerItems = spinnerItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mDataSource.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mDataSource.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.select_event_charge_items, null);
        }

        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_item_textview);
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.row_item_spinner);

        textView.setText(mDataSource.get(position));
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, mSpinnerItems);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setTag(position);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(mSpinnerItemSelectedListener);

        return view;
    }

    public void setOnSpinnerItemSelectedListener(AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener listener){
        this.mSpinnerItemSelectedListener = listener;
    }

}
```

Code in Main Activity

```
private void sortArrayList() {
        
            AdapterSelectEventPayment adapter = new AdapterSelectEventPayment(participants, chargeArray, this);

            adapter.setOnSpinnerItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                    System.out.println("The spinner has been spun... and position is " + position + " and the id = " + id);
                    System.out.println("Tag is " + selectedItemView.getTag());
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                    System.out.println("The spinner has NOT been spun...");
                }
            });

            lvSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Comment: I see that you have a listener for spinner in your adapter `mSpinnerItemSelectedListener` but your activity has a different listener for your spinner. Could you please explain?

Comment: Could you post the entirety of you Adapter class? I think you may be missing a crucial `onItemClickListener` containing the position of the item click.

Comment: Thanks to you both for responding. I've posted the full adapter. The difference in the name of the listener is just down to how it was defined, but it's working insofar as when it's used it triggers the onItemSelected() in the main activity.

Comment: @WarrenHarding Can you please do `getTag` on `parentView` rather than `selectedItemView` and check?

Comment: @akhilnair That was it. Thank you so much. I should have figured that one out myself - but I've been looking at it for hours. Thanks again for your help. (Not sure how I can upvote your answer).

Comment: @WarrenHarding I can add an answer and then you can upvote. That would be nice of you.

Comment: @akhilnair LOL - unfortunately my reputation doesn’t allow me to upvote your answer. As soon as I hit the 15 I’ll do it. Thanks again.

Comment: @WarrenHarding That would be great but for now you can surely accept my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling `getTag` on `selectedItemView` call it on  `parentView`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you create an interface that calls you back with all the relevant information from the Spinner selection + the position of the item clicked

```java
interface ListSpinnerListener() {
    void onSpinnerItemSelected(int rowPos, int selectedItemPos, ...);
}
```

that your Activity could assign the way your assigning the `AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener`, and instead utilize that listener directly inside of you `getView()` method

Adapter:

```java
private ListSpinnerListener listSpinnerListener;

...

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.select_event_charge_items, null);
    }

    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_item_textview);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.row_item_spinner);

    textView.setText(mDataSource.get(position));
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, mSpinnerItems);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setTag(position);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int itemPosition, long id) {
            System.out.println("The spinner has been spun... and position is " + position + " and the id = " + id);
            System.out.println("Tag is " + selectedItemView.getTag());
            listSpinnerListener.onSpinnerItemSelectedListener(position, itemPosition, ...);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
            System.out.println("The spinner has NOT been spun...");
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

That way you make sure you get all of the relevant information you need all the time thru a simple interface and without having to hack your way into the answer thru tags and whatnot.

Comment: Thank you for this. It makes sense and I will give it a go. Is there anywhere in particular I should define the interface? Thanks

Comment: That's very much up to you. I used a single-method interface that can be converted into a lambda with Java 8 and/or Kotlin if you're into that. But in reality, you have full control over this class and you should implement it based on your specific needs.

Comment: Thanks again for your help.